# Python Mechanize won't properly handle a redirect

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm working on a scraper using Mechanize and Beautiful Soup in Python and for some reason redirects aren't working. Here's my code (I apologize for naming my variables "thing" and "stuff"; I don't normally do that, trust me):

```
stuff = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'paging'}).ul.findAll('a', href=True)
    for thing in stuff:
        pageUrl = thing['href']
        print pageUrl

        req = mechanize.Request(pageUrl)

        response = browser.open(req)

        searchPage = response.read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(searchPage)
        soupString = soup.prettify()
        print soupString
```

Anyway, products on Kraft's website that have more than one page for search results display a link to go the next page(s). The source code lists, for example, [this](http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&brandid=1&searchtext=a.1.%20steak%20sauces%20and%20marinades&pageno=2) as the next page for Kraft's line of steak sauces and marinades, which redirects to [this](http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&brandid=1&searchtext=a.1.%20steak%20sauces%20and%20marinades&pageno=2)

Anyway, `thing['href']` has the old link in it because it scrapes the web page for it; one would think that doing `browser.open()` on that link would cause mechanize to go to the new link and return that as a response. However, running the code gives this result:

```
http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&brandid=1&searchtext=a.1. steak sauces and marinades&pageno=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Development\eclipse\mobile development\Crawler\src\Kraft.py", line 58, in <module>
response = browser.open(req)
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 408: Request Time-out
```

I get a time-out; I imagine it's because, for some reason, mechanize is looking for the old URL and isn't being redirected to the new one (I also tried this with urllib2 and received the same result). What's going on here?

Thanks for the help and let me know if you need any more information.

Update: Alright, I enabled logging; now my code reads:

```
req = mechanize.Request(pageUrl)
print logging.INFO
```

When I run it I get this:

url argument is not a URI (contains illegal characters) u'http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&brandid=1&searchtext=a.1. steak sauces and marinades&pageno=2'
20

Update 2 (which occurred while writing the first update): It turns out that it was the spaces in my string! All I had to do was this: `pageUrl = thing['href'].replace(' ', "+")` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I would suggest you using https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests instead of mechanize or urllib2 to do the http requests. Will save you lots of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `urllib2` and `mechanize` openers include a handler for redirect responses by default (you can check looking at the `handlers` attribute), so I don't think the problem is that a redirect response isn't being correctly followed.

To troubleshoot the problem, you should capture the traffic in your web browser (in firefox, [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) are useful to do this) and compare it with the logs from your script (I'd recommend subclassing `urllib2.BaseHandler` to create your own handler to log all the information you need for every request and add the handler to your opener object using the `add_handler` method).